# Flatten a list of Anorm tuples

Tags: scala, anorm

Given a scala list such as:

```scala
List( ~(OuterObj,InnerObj1), ~(OuterObj, InnerObj2), ...)
```

Where all the OuterObj's are the same and the InnerObj's can be different, I need to "group" this into a single OuterObj object that contains a list of the InnerObj's.

In other words, `OuterObj` has an attribute `innerList` that is empty, but I need to transform the original list into a single OuterObj such that:

```
OuterObj.innerList = List(InnerObj1, InnerObj2, ....)
```

I tried using `.groupBy(_._1)` but this didn't group the objects properly and I wasn't sure where to go from there.

In case context helps, the original List is a result of an Anorm join query with a one-to-many (1 outerObj to many innerObj) using the following parser pattern:

```scala
SQL(" joining outer on inner sql using a left join.. ").as(OuterObj.parse ~ InnerObj.parse *) // this is what creates the list of tuples
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tuples                            // List[(A, B)]
    .groupBy(_._1)                // Map[A , List[(A, B)]
    .mapValues(_.map(_._2))       // Map[A, List[B]]
    .toList                       // List[(A, List[B])]
    .map{ case (parent, children) =>
        parent.copy(
            innerList = children
        )
    }                             // List[A]
```

Using an outer join you really ought to parse the inner objects optionally, otherwise you'll lose rows where there are no inner objects (unless that is the desired effect). In which case, you'd do:

```
SQL(...).as(OuterObj.parse ~ (InnerObj.parse ?) *) // List[(A, Option[B])]                    
    .groupBy(_._1)                // Map[A , List[(A, Option[B])]
    .mapValues(_.map(_._2))       // Map[A, List[Option[B]]]
    .toList                       // List[(A, List[Option[B]])]
    .map{ case (parent, children) =>
        parent.copy(
            innerList = children.flatten
        )
    }                             // List[A]
```

Comment: I am using a left outer join. I thought that would prevent me from losing rows when the inner objects aren't present? And you are right, I do not want to lose rows of "outer" when they don't have a corresponding "inner"

Comment: Right. The query will keep the rows, but the parser will not if it doesn't see the inner object (when the inner parser is not optional).

Comment: This works up until the mapValues call: it is returning a Map[A, List[A]].  It seems to be eliminating B (inner object)

Comment: ahh I fixed it by changing the map to: _.map(_._2) instead of _.map(_._1)

Comment: Whoops. Sorry about that. Typo.

Comment: This worked great.  2 final questions, what would be the best way for me to return A instead of List[A] (the query _should_ return only a single result).  And lastly more of a soft question: while your sequence of transformations is genius, it seems a bit convoluted to me being new to Scala.  Is this typical / natural / what-I-should-be-expected-to-do using Scala (and perhaps Play)?

Comment: and just to clarify - when I say the query should return a single result, I meant that after the grouping is done there will only be a single outer object (since I have a where clause filtering by primary key)

Comment: Add `headOption` at the end of the chain, since there should be only one object in the final list (or none).

Comment: Sorry, missed your other comment before. It is a bit convoluted, and can be simplified a bit (mapValues isn't 100% necessary.. just easier to read later), but this is about as complicated as it gets for my Play apps (except for more nesting).